# Searching through books to get Author (Java)

Tags: java, loops, search, arraylist

Im trying to look through my list of books and return all the books by that particular author. Im getting back an empty list.

```
public ArrayList<Book> searchByAuthor(Author author) {
    ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < myBooks.size(); i++) {
        if (myBooks.get(i).getMyAuthors().contains(author)) {
            bookList.add(myBooks.get(i));      
        }
    }
    return bookList;
}



public ArrayList<Author> getMyAuthors() {
        return myAuthors;
    }
```

The main looks somethings like this.

```
Author author = new Author("James");
System.out.println(bookCollections.searchByAuthor(author));
```

Comment: What does the equals implementation of `Author` look like?

Comment: Is Author parameter same as in getMyAuthors() or did you create a new object?

Comment: Looks like equals is not implemented. See this
[How to use contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332059/how-to-use-contains-on-custom-type-arraylist-in-java/46332573#46332573)

Comment: I don't have an equal method in my Author.. maybe thats why

Comment: Possible duplicate (can't change my close-vote reason): [ArrayList's custom Contains method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8322129). For more duplicates use your favorite searching engine and search for `java list contains custom object`. You can add `site:stackoverflow.com` at google to limit results to this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Author object is a value object. you need to implement both `equals` and `hashcode` methods in your Author.java class.